# Is this wikipedia code for quickselect incorrect?

Tags: algorithm

I was reading the quickselect algorithm on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

```
  function select(list, left, right, k)
     if left = right        // If the list contains only one element,
         return list[left]  // return that element
     pivotIndex  := ...     // select a pivotIndex between left and right,
                            // e.g., left + floor(rand() % (right - left + 1))
     pivotIndex  := partition(list, left, right, pivotIndex)
     // The pivot is in its final sorted position
     if k = pivotIndex
         return list[k]
     else if k < pivotIndex
         return select(list, left, pivotIndex - 1, k)
     else
         return select(list, pivotIndex + 1, right, k - pivotIndex)
```

Isn't the last recursive call incorrect? I believe it the last argument should just be `k` rather than `k - pivotIndex`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right - the last correction from September 20 introduced this error.

Top comment says that

```
// Returns the k-th smallest element of list within left..right inclusive
// (i.e. left <= k <= right).
```

and `k` is defined over all index range, it is absolute, not relative to local low border, as you noticed in comment.

Aslo checked my implementation of `kselect`, it uses `k` in the second call.

Comment: Yes, that would work if `pivotIndex` was relative to the value of `left`, but it is the absolute index within the list